# Is there a way to view the suggested edits rankings?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rankings, trivial

I don't know if I can find it but I want to know who has the most approved suggested edits? I was able to check the edit rankings for a user but those included users with full editing rights.

What about one for just suggested edits?

Comment: It's not a contest.  It's a way to improve the site.  If you're more concerned about rankings you're likely doing it wrong.

Comment: @Servy No no I'm not concerned it's just I was wondering if there is one. I'm not asking for a feature request.

Comment: Yes, on http://data.stackexchange.com/ . I haven't looked to see if someone's already written a query for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For suggested edits, your "ranking" is paid in cash on the spot once approved (2 rep), why bother to create a ranking system for it ;)

Anyway, if you keep up the good work you will have the full edit right, then you will have the ranking you are craving for.

Comment: Yeah but sometimes there might be people with more than 500 suggested edits, those who gain rep very slowly. Oh well guess there is no feature then. EDIT: Saw your edited and yeah I hope I will get 2k soon

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no ranking system because frankly it would not be useful. The purpose of suggested edits is to introduce you to the editing system through peer review so that (hopefully) when you receive your full editing privileges, you'll have some sort of idea of what you're supposed to be doing with them. It also provides a small amount of reputation to help users along who aren't as into asking and answering. It's not a competition, and giving any sense of competition would likely end up being counter-productive.

Comment: Oh I see. The thing is, there is no real benefit for users under 2k but got a gold editor badge eh? Btw, is there a query to find the person with the most suggested edits, just out of curiosity?

Comment: Just as there is no real benefit for a user above 2k who has the gold editor badge. They edit because the post needs fixed and it will make our community a better place, simple as that.